# How to link to a specific tweet when you don't know the user.screen_name?

Tags: twitter

**This** has probably been asked, but I can't find it...

I want to link to a specific tweet, such as this:

http://twitter.com/TinyNietzsche/status/69440267110973440

But if `@TinyNietzsche` changes his screen_name it breaks my link.

Using the *API*, statuses/show I can get the raw data, and even build a link to twitter using that, but that doesn't really seem efficient.

I can create a persistent link to the user by using the redirect:

http://twitter.com/account/redirect_by_id?id=131891655

Is there a way to link a specific tweet that doesn't rely on the user.screen_name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just replace their user name with their user id:

http://twitter.com/#!/131891655/status/69440267110973440

Comment: Wonderful, and by the speed of the response I assume this has been asked before. You got the checkmark!

Comment: @BentFX actually I don't think I've seen that asked before, and I hang out on the twitter dev list quite often. It was more of an educated guess that I tested and it worked :)

Comment: It's really a non-issue, but I assume if someone changes their screen_name to 131891655 the links broken again, correct?

Comment: @BentFX That's certainly an issue, but I'm not sure how the Twitter backend works, so I'm not sure if it would pick the user ID over the screen name

Comment: @onteria_ good guess! I had just dealt with the user.id_str link, and searched out the redirect url. So I never thought the id would work in the link to the tweet. Thanks, and thanks again.

Comment: `user_id`s will never change for a user. This solution is a bit of a hack though as it only works on #newtwitter so if Twitter ever has to rollback to the old site it will stop working. It work solely off of the `status_id` so you can actually put anything in place of the `screen_name`. Eg: https://twitter.com/#!/x/status/69440267110973440

Comment: @abraham Thanks, that seems to be the bottom line. (unless they do a rollback) BTW, thanks for twitteroauth, it's working good on this end.